# How to positioning in ASP.NET Grid

Tags: asp.net, grid

I am new to .NET. I am facing a problem . My question is that I have a data grid control and I am using the asp text boxes in my grid instead of the bound field. In my grid there is a blank row at the top and user can enter the data in these text boxes and after entering the and press the enter I want that my grid is position from the values entered by the user. Means the row at top is matching the data enter by the user.

Answer (score 0):

what is the positioning problem? can you post the code?

```
select * from trnhst order by xwe4nb desc
```

the above sql query places the newest on top

Comment: Actually positioning is not the problem . I want to know how to do the positioning in the ASP grid view if u want then I post my .aspx and handler.
Again I want to mention that I want that the starting position of my grid start from the given value.

Comment: @capsoft: Do not use answers to ask supplementary questions, use the add comment feature under the question instead.

Comment: @prashant mishra you mean order by? please post the code for filling the grid.
@anthonywjones sorry!

Comment: Not orderby
  // Prepare query
  StringBuilder qry =
   new StringBuilder("SELECT XWE4NB, XWDLDT, XWC8DT, XWRICD, XWBNCD, ")
    .Append("XWBCCD, XWABCD, XWAACS, XWT8TX, XWORDN, ")
    .Append("XWAGCD, XWAHCD, XWAICD, PERSON, XWBDCD")
   .Append(" FROM TRNHST");
this is my query and 

                DataGrid.DataSource = rs;
  DataBind();

and this is the code for filling the data

Comment: and with select * from trnhst order by xwe4nb desc ?